# Start matlab with command line takes several seconds

Tags: matlab

I am now trying to run matlab code with command line. Like this:

```
matlab -nojvm -nosplash -nodisplay -r "sum(1,2);exit;"
```

But matlab itsef takes a long time to start, around 3 seconds. It can be too long for some applications. And the terminal shows:

```
                        < M A T L A B (R) >
              Copyright 1984-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.
               R2016a (9.0.0.341360) 64-bit (glnxa64)
         February 11, 2016For online documentation, see http://www.mathworks.com/support For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
```

Is there a way to speed up this process or there exists matlab runtime product that can link some toolbox? I don't have matlab distributed server.

Comment: May be not necessary that it is related to matlab. Run ps -e to see processes running in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to start Matlab in a separate process and talk to it through a Unix pipe. That way you can always have it running in the background.

Note that this solution doesn't support concurrent executions of Matlab.